# Escape JSON_VALUE with colon

Tags: json, sql-server

I need to know how to use a ":" (colon) in json_value in SQL Server.

For example:

```
SELECT 
json_value(tags,'$.is_in:state')
FROM testdata
```

The error:

> JSON path is not properly formatted. Unexpected character ':'

Comment: JSON string values are surrounded by double-quotes, not single-quotes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try double quotes.

```
SELECT json_value(tags, '$."is_in:state"')
       FROM testdata;
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response!  Exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

I was having problems with newtonsoft.json full assembly type generated

```
"$id": "1",
  "$type": "Pew.Pewer, Pewy",
  "Producers": {
    "$type": "System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`1[[Pew.Peweeee, Pewy]], System.Collections",
    "$values": []
  },
```

adding to sticky bit's answer

```
SELECT 
json_value(payload, '$."$id"') as id
json_value(payload, '$."$type"') as type
FROM LoadMyPay;
```